# Excel sum values if categories aren't found in a list (better coding method)

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have this code below in the form of an array and I was wondering if there was a cleaner and more dynamic way to code it. (I have removed the $ just to make it easier to read)

```
SUMPRODUCT(IF((A1:A10 <> D1)*(A1:A10 <> D2),B1:B10))
```

- Column A has a list of names
- Column B has a list of values
- Column D has a list of names not to include in the calculation

The issue with this formula is that for each new item in column D I have to append another * which would start to make a massive formula.
I tried `SUMPRODUCT(IF((A1:A10 <> D1:D2),B1:B10))` but it did not work. Does anyone have any ideas?

P.S. You have to hit CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER to make the cell an array, the formula wont work otherwise.

EDIT: and I can't have `D1:DX` be the same size as the other ranges as I need the X to be dynamic for my specific scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use a helper column to find the "good" rows.  In **C1** enter:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,D:D,0)),1,0)
```

and copy down.  Each "good" name is marked with a *1*.  In another cell:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(C1:C100)*B1:B100)
```

For example:

[image]

The "helper " column avoids the need for an array formula. You can have as many "bad" names in column **D** as you like without having to change the formula.

Comment: I don't think you need the `--()` in the formula as the helper column is already 0 and 1. Even if it was TRUE and FALSE the formula `=SUMPRODUCT(C1:C100*B1:B100)` would have worked.

Comment: So your formula in Col C could be just `=ISERROR(MATCH(A1,D:D,0))`

Comment: @nightcrawler23  You are correct! ..... I use **--()** to remind me that the term corresponds to an array of 1's and 0's ..... it's a mental crutch.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this formula in 'E1':

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B:$B,ISERROR(MATCH($A:$A,$D:$D,0))*1)
```

[image]